# tmux.conf: if in key-bindings

Tags: syntax, config, tmux

*(sorry, bad english)*
**My goal**: execute a **different command** depending on a "variable", but with **one key-binding**.

I want to **de/activate the pane-synchronization** with S (capital s), because the little s is in use to show the different sessions, but I really dont know how to write that. (Of course I could rebind s, but that little s for Sessions is branded in my mind)

I thought maybe something like this:
`bind S "if (snychronize-panes=on)"; then "setw synchronize-panes off": else "setw synchronize-panes on"`

I tried replacing the "synchronize-panes" with a variable, but I dont know how to write a corret if-clause in the tmux.conf.

Comment: `bind-key -n C-k if-shell 'test #{window_panes} -gt 1' 'select-pane -t :.-1' 'send-keys C-k'` is how I do a key bind to determine whether or not ctrl+k should select the next pane or send ctrl+k to the terminal, though I don't know how to test whether synchronize-panes is on or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, using the built-in variable `pane_synchronized` and the format version of *if-then-else*: `#{?expression,value-if-true,value-if-false}`:

```
bind-key S set-window-option -F synchronize-panes #{?pane_synchronized,off,on}
```

and as Nicholas Marriott says in the comments, if no value is provided to a on/off option, it will simply toggle, so you can simply have:

```
bind-key S set-window-option synchronize-panes
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. Do you use that as a sort of tuple where you rotate through by clicking "S"?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. When you type the S and you are in synch mode then variable `#{pane_synchronized}` has the value 1. The resulting expression is therefore `#{?1,off,on}` which has value "off". (The opposite case of `#{?0,off,on}` would have the value "on".) So the final command is `set-window-option synchronize-panes off`.  By the way, I've added `-F` to the answer, as some versions of tmux may need it to ensure the value `#{...}` is treated as a Format.  Don't forget to click the *tick* next to the answer so other readers know it should work for them.

Comment: If you do `set synchronize-panes` (without `on` or `off`) then tmux will toggle the option.